# beamer's fragile frame as default

Tags: beamer, verbatim

Is there a way to specify *fragile* mode as default for all frames? Now I know how to define a fragile frame: `\begin{frame}[fragile]`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could define your own frame environment like it is explained in the user manual p.62, e.g.:

```
\newenvironment{xframe}[2][]
  {\begin{frame}[fragile,environment=xframe,#1]
  \frametitle{#2}}
  {\end{frame}}
```

The `environment` option does the trick. It tells `beamer` that the frame ends with an `\end{xframe}` now.

Note that the `frame` has a complex set of optional arguments, including two `< >` and to *optional*(!) braced arguments for the frame title and sub-title. Not all of these arguments might be supported by the above code. You might write it better as:

```
\newenvironment{xframe}[1][]
  {\begin{frame}[fragile,environment=xframe,#1]}
  {\end{frame}}
```

which should support both optional title and sub-title arguments.
You also can define the frame title using an explicit `\frametitle` command.

Another, more complex alternative is to use the `xparse` package to define `xframe` with the same arguments of `frame` and pass it along.

Comment: Is there a way to set fragile as default for frame, instead of creating xframe?

Comment: @Majoko: I'm not aware of one.