# Problem using \textblock with \newenvironment

Tags: beamer, environments

I want to redefine the `frame` environment in `beamer` so that the contents are inside a box in the center of the frame, but when I try defining the new environment like:

```
\newenvironment{hframe}[1]
{%before
\begin{frame}{{#1}}
\begin{textblock}{11}(2,2)
}{ %after
\end{textblock}
\end{frame}
}

...

\begin{document}

...

\begin{hframe}{title}
some text
\end{hframe}

\end{document}
```

I got a compiling error: `"! File ended while scanning use of \frame."`. But if instead I use the following code

```
\newenvironment{hframe}[1]
{%before
\begin{frame}{{#1}}
\begin{textblock}{11}(2,2)
}{ %after
%\end{textblock}
\end{frame}
}

...

\begin{document}

...

\begin{hframe}{title}
some text
\end{textblock}
\end{hframe}

\end{document}
```

it works... Any clue of what is happening and how can I include the `\end{textblock}` in the "end" argument of `\newenvironment`?

Comment: Perhaps this question will help: [beamer's fragile frame as default](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11328/beamers-fragile-frame-as-default/).  But keep in mind that while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it

Answer (score 1):

You *cannot* wrap the `beamer` frame environment up like this: it's more-or-less a verbatim situation. You'll need instead to create the appropriate `beamer` theme, which is constructed after the frame is collected.

Answer (score 1):

Section 8.1 *The Frame Environment* in the `beamer` user guide explains why TeX misses your `\end{frame}` when it is part of your own environment.

Joseph's suggestion of creating an appropriate theme is a better idea, but (as also explained in that section of the guide) you can pass the `fragile` option to the `frame`, and tell it the name of your enclosing environment with the `environment=hframe` option. Note however the consequences of using `fragile`.

As you haven't provided a full MWE, this is the best I can do to help you achieve what you were trying:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{textpos}

\newenvironment{hframe}[1]
{%before
\begin{frame}[fragile,environment=hframe]{{#1}}
\begin{textblock}{11}(2,2)
}{%after
\end{textblock}
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{hframe}{title}
some text
\end{hframe}

\end{document}
```