# Drawbacks of using fragile frames in beamer

Tags: beamer

This is a follow up on [beamer's fragile frame as default](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11328/beamers-fragile-frame-as-default). What are the drawbacks of setting the default frame to be fragile (or passing the optional fragile argument to all frames). The [beamer user guide](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) says

> If a frame contains fragile text, different internal mechanisms are
>   used to typeset the frame to ensure that inside the frame the
>   character codes can be reset. The price of switching to another
>   internal mechanism is that either you cannot use overlays or an
>   external file needs to be written and read back (which is not always
>   desirable).

Presumably writing and reading a file takes time and so this increases the time it takes to compile, but are there things that do not work in a fragile frame?

As for an MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\def\foo{Something that makes the fragile frame fail is: }
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \foo
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \foo
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I am trying to understand what `\foo` would need to be defined as to cause problems.

Comment: The only issue that I remember encountering so far is in debugging. If you get an error (e.g. `\foo` is undefined), then without `fragile`, you get the line number of the `\end{frame}` in which the error occurred. On the other hand, with `fragile`, you just get the line number within the frame (the `.vrb` file), not of the frame itself.

Comment: It's difficult to define a new command in a `fragile` frame.

Comment: @PaulGaborit Doing `\newcommand{\bar}{bar}` inside a fragile frame doesn't work, but `\def\bar{}\renewcommand{\bar}{bar}` does work. I think `\newcommand` fails because of the writing a file and reading it back in issue, making this a potential answer. That said, the need to use `\newcommand` within a frame and the simple work around, means it is not much of a drawback.

Comment: @StrongBad Any verbatim stuff doesn't work inside a non-fragile frame (i.e. source code listings).

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159172/build-kind-of-a-includeonlypart-for-beamer for one case in which the need to use `fragile` proved problematic and the solution to the problem involved an alternative approach which avoided the need for `fragile`.

Comment: @cfr Thanks for the lead. It is not quite what I was thinking, but it does show a way to cause a fragile frame to fail.

Comment: From my testing, [fragile] can't be used when the presentation is wrapped in `\mode<presentation> { ... }`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

there are no important drawbacks. It is also possible to define a new environment with the `fragile` option:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newenvironment{Foo}[1]
  {\begin{frame}[environment=Foo]{#1}}
  {\end{frame}}

\newenvironment{FooBar}[1]
  {\begin{frame}[fragile,environment=FooBar]{#1}}
  {\end{frame}}
\begin{document}

\begin{Foo}{title} 
\end{Foo}

\begin{FooBar}{title}
\end{FooBar}

\end{document}
```

With fragile *every contents* is written into an external file and read back. Not a big deal but makes compiling slow. However, `fragile` is needed for verbatim material.

Comment: Well, does that mean that the option is useless and it should be activated always directly by the class? That seems strange to me :-/

Comment: no, with `fragile` _every_  contents is written into an external file and read back. Not a big deal but makes compiling slow.

Comment: Be aware of the effects on centering described in my answer.

Answer (score 12):

See [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/317712/73149). Apparently the `fragile` option is incompatible with the `allowframebreaks` option, without some awkward finagling. So that's one drawback, in addition to the much slower compilation mentioned in the comments of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

The `fragile` option has some impact on centering:

```tex
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \centering
    center
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \centering
    not center
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \begin{center}
        center again
    \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```