# An "implies" version of diagonal arrows (such as \nwarrow)

Tags: arrows

I am trying to write a simple commutative diagram using an array. I know that there are fancier ways to do this, but for my purposes this is quick and simple and means I don't have to look up things I have previously half-remembered. Or so I thought.

My question is: how can I get an "implies" version of the diagonal arrows, such as `\nwarrow`? The standard way of doing this is to capitalise the first letter (`\rightarrow` becomes `\Rightarrow`, `\uparrow` becomes `\Uparrow`, etc.). However, as I'm sure you realised (because I am asking this question!) `\Nwarrow` doesn't work.

My MWE is below, and there is a picture of what is produced. I want the diagonal arrow to have the same forms as the other two arrows. "Simple" solutions would be appreciated; I can cobble something together myself using tikz, but this seems like overkill.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{ccc}
A&\Rightarrow&B\\
&\nwarrow&\Downarrow\\
&&C
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: picture of diagram]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\rotatebox` from `graphicx` to rotate symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand*{\Nwarrow}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{135}{\(\Longrightarrow\)}}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{c@{\ }c@{\ }c}
A&\Rightarrow&B\\
&\Nwarrow&\Downarrow\\
&&C
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I do not see how this is an overkill:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[arrows=Rightarrow]
A\arrow[r]&B\arrow[d]\\
&\arrow[ul]C
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[sep=small,arrows=Rightarrow]
A\arrow[r]&B\arrow[d]\\
&\arrow[ul]C
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I had actually written something like this already, and it was one of the reasons for my asking the question. I know I didn't say it in the question (for the sake of not over-complicating things), but one of the reasons for my not using tikz-cd is that I'm also using beamer, and they don't play nice together. So your code does not work unless I start my frame with `\begin{frame}[fragile]`. However, I don't understand why this is needed and its all getting a bit too complicated! Thus my plea for simplicity :-) [In fact, I only learned how to get tikz-cd to work after asking the question.]

Comment: @user1729 This does not have much to do with simplicity (or the lack of simplicity), but with the way beamer and LaTeX work. You can equally well use an `ampersand replacement`. You will run also in related problems when you try to define a macro with parameters in a frame. Of course, everyone is free to choose to produce the output in the way they want, but I personally would think that adding a `fragile` is simpler than tuning distances and rotation angles, which you would have to do once you want a more general diagram.

Comment: Well, my issue was really that I didn't understand why the error was occurring. Tikz itself seems to play fine with beamer. But I've now been looking at the tikz-cd documentation and it seems that the reason for the lack of issues was that I wasn't using matrices in my TikZ, as apparently "TikZ makes the character & active inside matrices". I don't really know what this means, apart from that the people/person who wrote the package know about the issue and have a suggestion for getting around it. Which makes any worries I had go away :-)

Comment: @user1729 This is a well-defined question, which however does not coincide with your above question. The fact that there is an active character does not explain the problem completely. However, a full explanation will depend on what you already know, and what you want to learn, and is certainly too much for a comment. I guess that the main issue is that the term `fragile` may not be optimally chosen, it sounds like "shaky" but there is no real downside in choosing `fragile`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/136240.