# Shaded verbatim and fragile frame

Tags: beamer, verbatim, typewriter

I have a `beamer` class file, with a plenty of `frame`s.
Almost all `frame`s need the option `[fragile]` because I frequently use `\verb| |` to illustrate codes. 
So I want the `frame` to be equipped with `[fragile]` globally so that I don't need to type the option manually.

Also, I want all the stuff inside `verbatim`(or possibly inside `\texttt`, but I prefer `verbatim`) to be grey-shaded, just as TeX exchange is doing now.

Here is a minimal working example.
Can you please modifiy it to resolve the issue?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile] % I used [fragile] since \verb in frame yields an error.
\frametitle{fragile frame and shaded verbatim}
\begin{itemize}
\item
I'm using the \verb|beamer| class.
\item
 want to set the \texttt{\colorbox{gray}{frame}} environment to be appended with the option \texttt{\colorbox{gray}{fragile}}.
\item
I want to set the stuff in the \texttt{\colorbox{gray}{verbatim}} command to be shaded just like \TeX exchange does.
\item
An ugly solution : \texttt{\colorbox{gray}{\textbackslash code\_example}}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: the proposed duplicate seems legit. However the approach proposed there does not work precisely with the `fragile` option (see comments in the linked question)

Answer (score 0):

Following the approach proposed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11331/177), you should write:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newenvironment{xframe}[1][]
{\begin{frame}[fragile,environment=xframe,#1]}
{\end{frame}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{xframe}% fragile option no longer required
        \frametitle{fragile frame and shaded verbatim}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item
            I'm using the \verb|beamer| class.
            \item
             want to set the \texttt{\colorbox{gray}{frame}} environment to be appended with the option \texttt{\colorbox{gray}{fragile}}.
            \item
            I want to set the stuff in the \texttt{\colorbox{gray}{verbatim}} command to be shaded just like \TeX exchange does.
            \item
            An ugly solution : \texttt{\colorbox{gray}{\textbackslash code\_example}}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{xframe}
\end{document}
```

I'm marking this question as duplicate, though.

Comment: I didn't know that there is a question like this. Thanks. But do you have any opinion about shaded verbatim?